# jQuery won't finish submitting properly and does unexpected things upon submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, forms

I am making a website that recommends subreddits for you by using the 'Reddit API'.

The project is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fw8jr4n8/5/). The site is best viewed in a maximised browser window at the moment because I'm not finished with the front-end.

It works by getting the inputted subreddits from the form and putting them in an array (using `.serializeArray()`). I also use the same function to get the omitted subreddits from the second form, too. It then gets the values and puts them together in a string. The final result (in the api variable) should be something like

http://www.reddit.com/api/recommend/sr/AskReddit,CasualConversation,?omit=SkypePals,

with the result:

```
[{"sr_name": "ForeverAloneWomen"}, {"sr_name": "southpaws"}, {"sr_name": "deaf"}, {"sr_name": "PointlessStories"}, {"sr_name": "intrusivethoughts"}, {"sr_name": "AMADisasters"}, {"sr_name": "Frat"}, {"sr_name": "GamerPals"}, {"sr_name": "Solving_A858"}, {"sr_name": "FindTheSniper"}]
```

depending on the inputted subreddits.
After this, it simply uses the api variable as a parameter for the `getJSON()` function, which returns the JSON response from Reddit into the json variable.

Then I use `each()` to iterate over the JSON response so that the recommended subreddits are put into the right column (beneath recommendations).

I've spent a very long time (several days) trying to fix this and it still doesn't work. When clicking the submit button, it refreshes the page and adds parameters into the address bar with the input of the form inputs. I don't know why this is.

Any help to fix this and avoid this in the future would be greatly appreciated. I can't get my head around this. I can't find anything that helps through searching either. I don't exactly know what the name of this issue is.

Apparently I am required to also provide code in this post as I linked to jsFiddle. I think my Javascript is most relevant so I'll provide that:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var api = "http://www.reddit.com/api/recommend/sr/";
    var json;
    var redditBaseLink = "http://www.reddit.com/r/";
    var srLink;
    var srArray;
    var srString = '';
    var omitArray, omitString;

    $(".srInputForm").submit(function (event) {
        srArray = $(this).serializeArray();
        $.each(srArray, function (i, field) {
            srString += field.value + ",";
        });
        api = api.concat(srString, "?omit=");

        $.each(omitArray, function (i, field) {
            omitString += field.value + ",";
        });
        api = api.concat(omitString);

        json = $.getJSON(api, function () {
            $.each(json, function (i, response) {
                srLink = "";
                srLink = '<div class="recommendation">' + '<a href="' + redditBaseLink + response.sr_name + '/" target="_blank">' + response.sr_name + '</a></div>';

                $(srLink).hide().appendTo(".recommendationsCol").fadeIn('slow');
            });
        });

        event.preventDefault;
        event.unbind;
    });
});
```

Thanks

**Edit 1:**

I have changed the code so that the `event.preventDefault;` function towards the bottom of the script is at the top of the `submit();` event handler. This seems to have worked, but now the script stops at another place, right after the `api = api.concat(srString, "?omit=` line, before the `$.each` loop for the omitted subreddits.

Here is my code with the debug stuff I put in:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var api = "http://www.reddit.com/api/recommend/sr/";
    var json;
    var redditBaseLink = "http://www.reddit.com/r/";
    var srLink;
    var srArray;
    var srString = '';
    var omitArray, omitString;

    // DEBUG CODE
    var codepoint = 0;
    function debug(alertMsg){
        codepoint++;
        alert(codepoint + ": " + alertMsg + " END MSG (refresh page after no more dialogs!!)");
        // copypasta call debug("");
    }

    $(".srInputForm").submit(function (event) {
        debug("after submit");
        event.preventDefault();
        debug("after preventDefault");
        srArray = $(this).serializeArray();
        debug("serialize array.");
        $.each(srArray, function (i, field) {
            srString += field.value + ",";
        });
        api = api.concat(srString, "?omit=");
        debug("after first api url making (no omit params). api url: " + api); // STOPS AFTER THIS LINE!

        $.each(omitArray, function (i, field) {
            omitString += field.value + ",";
        });
        api = api.concat(omitString);
        debug("final api url making, w/ omit params. api url: " + api);

        json = $.getJSON(api, function () {
            debug("JSON get");
            $.each(json, function (i, response) {
                srLink = "";
                debug("iteration " + i + ". srLink: " + srLink);
                srLink = '<div class="recommendation">' + '<a href="' + redditBaseLink + response.sr_name + '/" target="_blank">' + response.sr_name + '</a></div>';
                debug("iteration " + i + ". srLink (after making): " + srLink);
                $(srLink).hide().appendTo(".recommendationsCol").fadeIn('slow');
                debug("iteration " + i + ". after append");
            });
        });
    });
});
```

I'm not too sure if I should make another thread for this new issue? Anybody know how I would go about correcting this? Thanks.

**Edit 2:**

Hey guys. Sorry about the late update. Been busy at school cracking at the coursework!

So, I have resolved the issue with my project this post was about!

One of the main contributors to my partial success was moving `event.preventDefault` to the top of the `submit()` function, giving it brackets because it is a function (`event.preventDefault()`.

If you'd like to see the JS code as of now, here it is:

```
/* jshint jquery:true*/
// omit feature is buggy. will fix later.

$(document).ready(function () {
    var api = "http://www.reddit.com/api/recommend/sr/";
    var redditBaseLink = "http://www.reddit.com/r/";
    var srLink;
    var srArray;
    var srString = '';
    //var omitArray = [];
    //var omitString;

    /*// DEBUG CODE
    var codepoint = 0;

    function debug(alertMsg) {
        codepoint++;
        alert(codepoint + ": " + alertMsg + " END MSG (refresh page after no more dialogs!!)");
        // copypasta call debug("");
    }*/

    $(".srInputForm").submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        srArray = $(this).serializeArray();
        // omitArray = $(".omitForm").serializeArray();

        $.each(srArray, function (i, field) {
            srString += field.value + ",";
        });
        api = api.concat(srString /*, "?omit="*/ );

        /*if (omitArray[1].value === "" && omitArray[2].value === "" && omitArray[3].value === "") {
            api.replace("?omit=", "/");
        } else {
            $.each(omitArray, function (i, field) {
                api += field.value + ",";
            });
        }*/

        $.ajax({
            //dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonp: false,
            type: 'GET',
            url: api,
            success: function (json) {
                $.each(json, function (i, response) {
                    srLink = '<div class="recommendation">' + '<a href="' + redditBaseLink + response.sr_name + '/" target="_blank">' + response.sr_name + '</a></div>';
                    $(srLink).hide().appendTo(".recommendationsCol").fadeIn('slow', function () {
                        console.log("Fade in successful.");
                    });
                    srLink = "";
                });
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log(arguments);
            }
        });
        api = "http://www.reddit.com/api/recommend/sr/";
    });
});
```

Once again, thanks for all the help. I've learned from this quite a bit.

Comment: **About your edit** When I debug it firebug I see an error around `$.each` after your first `concat` call, because omitArray is `undefined`.

Comment: You don't use your `omitArray` var, I don't see anywhere in code where it is defined.

Comment: you ajax calls are wrong. you have no callback for the data. also, instead of `serializeArray()` use `serialize()`

Answer (score 0):

The reason it refreshes the page is because you are submitting a form. To be frank, your question is not very clear, but what I understand is that when a user clicks the submit button; you do not want to submit to form but make an ajax call instead. You can prevent a form from submitting by using event.preventDefault.

Try changing your code to be like

```
//Previous code    
.submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
//code continues
```

If this does not solve your problem, try cleaning up your queston a bit to be more clear and understandable.

Comment: Ya OP was using `event.preventDefault;` which has no effect (just as `event.unbind`)

Comment: These do not work, because preventDefault() is a **function**, I was not aware though of event.unbind but I guess it is another **function**.

Comment: @WolfEdge Check the browsers console. Does it throw an error on the line that it stops executing?

Answer (score 0):

You made a small mistake in the writing, `.preventDefault()` is a **function**, therefore it should be followed by parentheses.

```
$(".srInputForm").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // It is a function, should include parentheses.
    srArray = $(this).serializeArray();
    $.each(srArray, function (i, field) {
        srString += field.value + ",";
    });
    api = api.concat(srString, "?omit=");

    $.each(omitArray, function (i, field) {
        omitString += field.value + ",";
    });
    api = api.concat(omitString);

    json = $.getJSON(api, function () {
        $.each(json, function (i, response) {
            srLink = "";
            srLink = '<div class="recommendation">' + '<a href="' + redditBaseLink + response.sr_name + '/" target="_blank">' + response.sr_name + '</a></div>';

            $(srLink).hide().appendTo(".recommendationsCol").fadeIn('slow');
        });
    });
});
```

Also, if you want to unbind your jQuery event from this object you should use:

```
$(this).unbind('submit');
```

After `event.preventDefault();`.

Voila !